# Is it possible to make alias a global via parameter binding?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In PowerShell Alias can be created in two ways as below.

Way 1:

```
function hello() {
[alias("HelloWorld")]
   param(
     [string] $name
   )
  Write-Host "Hello $name!"
}
```

Way 2:

```
Set-Alias HelloWorld hello
```

In the `Set-Alias` way we can pass `-Scope` and make it as global.

Is it possible to make the Alias as global in the first way? 
(The reason for asking is that I have used a first way in my module but the alias is not visible when calling from another module).

Comment: You can't make an alias like you describe in Way 1. You make an alias of input property name. Like so:    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [Alias('HelloWorld')]
        [string] $name
   )

Comment: @KirillPashkov: Surprisingly, it actually does work, but I agree that it should be avoided to prevent confusion with parameter aliases.

Answer (score 3):

If you are treating this as a 'real' module (i.e. loading via `Import-Module`) and not just calling it as an external script, you can export the alias by adding this to the end of your module:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Alias HelloWorld
```

Get more info here: [Export-ModuelMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-6)

Alternatively, you can add this information to the [module manifest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878297(v=vs.85).aspx), if you are using one.

If you want to call it as an external script, remove the `[Alias()]` decoration and add this to the end:

```
Set-Alias -Name HellowWorld -Value hello
```

Make sure to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6) the script.  That is, call it like this:

```
. .\MyScript.ps1
```

**EDIT:**
For 'real' modules aliases, functions, etc are exported by default.  You would use the `Export-ModuleMember` to only export those you wanted users to see and hide everything else (e.g. to stop them seeing internal helper functions)

Answer (score 0):

[boxdog's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837248/45375) tells you how to define and export aliases the right way.

As for **your use of attribute `[alias("HelloWorld")]` to create a *command* alias** (to allow `HelloWorld` to invoke command (function) `hello`):

Even though it *happens to work*, it **isn't documented and shouldn't be relied upon**, not least because of potential confusion with *parameter* aliases (see below):

```
function hello() {
[alias("HelloWorld")] # Do NOT define a command alias for 'hello' this way.
   param(
   # ...
```

**To create *command* aliases, use `Set-Alias` or `New-Alias`**, as shown in boxdog's answer.

---

**The purpose of the `[Alias()]` attribute is to create *parameter* aliases**, i.e., to allow a given command's *parameters* to be referred to by a different name; from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.aliasattribute?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), emphasis added:

> Declares an alternative name *for a parameter*

For instance, if you wanted to define `-FirstName` as an alias for the `-Name` parameter in your example:

```
function hello() {
   param(
     [alias('FirstName')] # alias() decorates *parameter* -Name ($Name)
     [string] $Name
   )
  Write-Host "Hello $Name!"
}
```

For instance, `hello -FirstName Mary` and `hello -Name Mary` would then be equivalent (but note that it is the `$Name` parameter *variable* that gets bound in *both* cases).